# How are distances walked counted when breeding multiple eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

Imagine I am breeding two eggs at the same time and walk one kilometer while playing Pokémon Go. Will both eggs count 1 km each or do they only increase by 500 meters each?

Comment: The GPS tracks how far you walk, it's the same concept as a car odometer, with a twist anything over 25 miles per hour won't be tracked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I walked a bit today and hatched about 4 eggs in 2 incubators. I experimented a bit, and apparently they both count the distance each (it won't be split out - both will get 1km after walking 1km).